# AES_ENCRYPT and collation issue

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, encryption

For a website I used a simple script to store formdata in a database. The data is encrypted using AES_ENCRYPT, the code I used is:

```
$pdo = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME,
    DB_USER,
    DB_PASSWORD
);

$hash = SECRET_HASH;

$p = $pdo->prepare("
    INSERT INTO entries
    (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES 
    (
        AES_ENCRYPT(:firstname, '{$hash}'), 
        AES_ENCRYPT(:lastname, '{$hash}'), 
        AES_ENCRYPT(:email, '{$hash}')
    )
");

$result = $p->execute(array(
    ':firstname' => $data['firstname'],
    ':lastname' => $data['lastname'],
    ':email' => $data['email']
));
```

This all works fine, and I could decrypt the data using this:

```
select id, cast(aes_decrypt(firstname,'<secrethash>') as char), cast(aes_decrypt(lastname,'<secrethash>') as char), cast(aes_decrypt(email,'<secrethash>') as char) from entries
```

The collation on the table columns is latin1_swedish_ci.

Now another person is using the site with his own database, which is PostgreSQL and not MySql. He tested it but couldn't decrypt the data. He told me he used utf-8 as a collation. The data he got in the database is something like this `JcXOomXShZ7d6`, whereas my data is something like `:,AfbIQlº˜Y¨¹Â`.

The problem is that there is already some data in his database that we want to decrypt, so I was wondering if there is any way to decrypt that data?

I don't know if the issue is due to PostgreSQL / MySQL or the wrong collation type. I tried to import the data to my database and run the query but that didn't work.

Comment: More importantly, what data type did he store the encrypted data in?